# detecting pauses in a spoken word audio file using pymad, pcm, vad, etc

Tags: mp3, pcm

First I am going to broadly state what I'm trying to do and ask for advice. Then I will explain my current approach and ask for answers to my current problems.

---

### Problem

I have an MP3 file of a person speaking. I'd like to split it up into segments roughly corresponding to a sentence or phrase. (I'd do it manually, but we are talking hours of data.)

If you have advice on how to do this programatically or for some existing utilities, I'd love to hear it. (I'm aware of voice activity detection and I've looked into it a bit, but I didn't see any freely available utilities.)

---

### Current Approach

I thought the simplest thing would be to scan the MP3 at certain intervals and identify places where the average volume was below some threshold. Then I would use some existing utility to cut up the mp3 at those locations.

I've been playing around with pymad and I believe that I've successfully extracted the PCM (pulse code modulation) data for each frame of the mp3. Now I am stuck because I can't really seem to wrap my head around how the PCM data translates to relative volume. I'm also aware of other complicating factors like multiple channels, big endian vs little, etc.

Advice on how to map a group of pcm samples to relative volume would be key.

Thanks!

Comment: I am in a similar boat. Did you get a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3):

PCM is a time frame base encoding of sound. For each time frame, you get a peak level. (If you want a physical reference for this: The peak level corresponds to the distance the microphone membrane was moved out of it's resting position at that given time.) 
Let's forget that PCM can uses unsigned values for 8 bit samples, and focus on 
signed values. If the value is > 0, the membrane was on one side of it's resting position, if it is < 0 it was on the other side. The bigger the dislocation from rest (no matter to which side), the louder the sound.

Most voice classification methods start with one very simple step: They compare the peak level to a threshold level. If the peak level is below the threshold, the sound is considered background noise. 
Looking at the parameters in Audacity's Silence Finder, the `silence level` should be that threshold. The next parameter, `Minimum silence duration`, is obviously the length of a silence period that is required to mark a break (or in your case, the end of a sentence).

If you want to code a similar tool yourself, I recommend the following approach:

1. Divide your sound sample in discrete sets of a specific duration. I would start with 1/10, 1/20 or 1/100 of a second.
2. For each of these sets, compute the maximum peak level
3. Compare this maximum peak to a threshold (the `silence level` in Audacity). The threshold is something you have to determine yourself, based on the specifics of your sound sample (loudnes, background noise etc). If the max peak is below your threshold, this set is silence.
4. Now analyse the series of classified sets: Calculate the length of silence in your recording. (length = number of silent sets * length of a set). If it is above your `Minimum silence duration`, assume that you have the end of a sentence here.

The main point in coding this yourself instead of continuing to use Audacity is that you can improve your classification by using advanced analysis methods. One very simple metric you can apply is called *zero crossing rate*, it just counts how often the sign switches in your given set of peak levels (i.e. your values cross the 0 line). There are many more, all of them more complex, but it may be worth the effort. Have a look at [discrete cosine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) for example...

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update this. I'm having moderate success using Audacity's Silence Finder. However, I'm still interested in this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

PCM is a way of encoding a sinusoidal wave.  It will be encoded as a series of bits, where one of the bits (1, I'd guess) indicates an increase in the function, and 0 indicates a decrease.  The function can stay roughly constant by alternating 1 and 0.

To estimate amplitude, plot the sin wave, then normalize it over the x axis.  Then, you should be able to estimate the amplitude of the sin wave at different points.  Once you've done that, you should be able to pick out the spots where amplitude is lower.

You may also try to use a Fourier transform to estimate where the signals are most distinct.

Comment: Your explanation of PCM encoding is incorrect, it just gives the amplitude for a time frame. Sinusiodal encoding is not used at all.